# On node view page show a link or button that executes an action?

Tags: rules, actions

The closest that comes to this for D5:
http://drupal.org/project/node_operations_block

I am familiar with creating VBO Actions, but not sure how to create it for a node operation. Such as a link or a button, that creates a new node with default values for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module to put that "button" on the node. Then using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) you could execute a [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) or simply use rules to create that content. Don't forget to look at [Rules Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/rb) for more goodies.

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/project/button_field may be useful.  From its description:

> Adds a button field type for use with CCK and Rules. [...]  When the button is clicked, an AJAX call is made that runs the Rules event. An optional URL can be specified for the button to redirect to after the AJAX call is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using https://drupal.org/project/rules_link
"This module lets you create links which trigger arbitrary functionality with the help of Rules."